# Rooting Android phone 2nd Attempt

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, unrooting

I rooted my smartphone **Huawei Honor Bee** five days ago, after a successful root, I uninstalled some unnecessary system apps. then I unrooted it successfully.

Question: If I attempt to root the smartphone again & again, is there any problem arising?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Is there any problem arise rooting my phone again` No, there's no problem.. You may do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no danger in you case with a Spreadtrum device, unless you have an issue in the following situations:

- Warranty: In some countries/regions warranty will be void because they don't want you to bother their after sales. maybe this is the only reason. But if you have a full flashable factory firmware you will avoid this case.
- Bootloader: Google/ODMs/OEMs/Carriers locks it because they simply don't want you to alter their configurations.
- Bricking: If you don't know exactly how to deal with root. rooting a device maybe dangerous and may lead to soft brick it, unless you have again a full flashable factory firmware. personally i never encountered a hard brick case while rooting MTK/Spreadtrum devices.
- Grant access to Adaware/Malware:- rooting is dangerous for newbies, it will let malicious apps to install unwanted Lock screens, unwanted software, view ads everywhere, etc...)

Why rooting a device is needed?

- You are bored from factory OS and want to try a custom OS if available.
- You a modder and want to tweak factory OS by removing bloatware or alter some system apps.
- If you are a developer, in some cases you should have root (controlling a serial device for example).

Comment: @vsal : you're welcome, if you feel this is the right reply, don't forget to accept it.